# What are some non-entertainment, real-world applications of more complicated mass-spring models?

Tags: mass, spring

What are some non-entertainment, real-world applications of more complicated mass-spring models? E.g. 3D models and models involving springs to multiple directions.

So far these models have seemed a bit too of a theoretical exercise.

Comment: Would a car with damping springs and security belts modeled as springs be an example, also bumping cars on a fair.

Comment: Or a suspension bridge carrying vehicles, a tall building being pushed around by the wind. Even sound propagation through a solid can be modeled with an array of mass elements connected by springs.

Answer (score 2):

Spring/mass/damper systems are routinely modeled for purposes of designing car, truck and motorcycle suspensions- for best performance under a variety of conditions. More advanced models of this general type can be written to include the effects of tire dynamics and frame flexure too.

The most complicated systems in this general class are those in which the mass, spring and damper elements are not modeled as "lumps" but instead as *distributed quantities* in extended (3D) systems, in which *wave propagation* becomes possible. A perfect example of a distributed system would be a suspension bridge which is being wiggled by wind forces (go watch a video of the *Tacoma Narrows bridge failure*). At the time it was built, computers were not advanced enough to allow modeling the response of a suspension bridge to cyclic wind loads, and so its failure mode could not be anticipated before construction began.

Such simulations nowadays are entirely routine.

Comment: Does "Such simulations nowadays are entirely routine." suggest that the right way to learn these methods is by using some packages, rather than learning the theory from scratch?

Comment: No, because you have to know system dynamics in order to set up the problem and then correctly interpret the results. I recommend  you read *System Dynamics: A Unified Approach* by Karnopp and Rosenberg. it's an old text but valuable.